# ContactsApp.getContact() for contact with multiple emails returns a different contact for each email address

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

My company allows employees to have multiple email addresses in their account.
I am attempting to write an input form where someone can enter any of the emails for a contact and we'll resolve it to the same person.

I've tried doing this via `ContactsApp.getContact(email).getPrimaryEmail()` to resolve all different inputs to the same primary email, but it doesn't work as expected. Each email I search for returns a different Contact object with only a single email (the one I used to search).

Even if I use `ContactsApp.getContact(email).getEmails()` to list all emails to the employee, I can see it only returns one at a time.

When going to contacts.google.com, I see the information I expected. Searching for any of the emails will return the same contact, with the same primary email and all other emails listed.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Or is this how ContactsApp works.  If so, is there a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the people API directly?

Comment: I could not reproduce this issue, it's returning all emails associated with a contact if I use `getEmails()`. How are additional emails being added to each account?

Answer (score 1):

`getPrimaryEmail()` will only return an email address if the contact in question has had a default email set and this can only be done via the Google Contacts App, not on the web (go figure).

To solve your problem I would suggest loading all the contacts into an array variable first and then searching this for matching email addresses.  I would do the data retrieval on page/view load (so it can be reused without multiple server calls) but have included it all together here for conciseness.

What I found strange about the `ContactsApp` (and presumable People API too) is that the contacts returned are just empty objects (when logged) with just a bunch of methods on them.  However, once you have an array of objects you can write your own properties to those objects for easier access of data.

Therefore I would first of all retrieve all the users contacts, then add a property of `.emails` to each contact object in the array and then use .some, perhaps, to check if a match appears in `.emails` (which will also be an array).

Something like:

```
let strSearch = 'someone@somewhere.net' // EMAIL address to search based on user input
let arrContacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();
let contacts = arrContacts.map(contact => {
      let emails = contact.getEmails();
      contact.emails = emails.map(email => email.getAddress());
      return contact;
      });
let foundContact = contacts.filter(contact => contact.emails.some(email => email === strSearch));
```

Remember `.getEmails()` returns another array of objects that have the method `.getAddress()` on them in order to retrieve the actual address, that's why I'm getting an array of email objects with `let emails = contact.getEmails();` then using `emails.map` here to put the actual email addresses into an array stored in the `contact.emails` property (that doesn't exist so we're actually creating it here).

After that we're filtering the `contacts` array down to a contact where the searched email address is matched to one of the email addresses in the `contact.emails` array.  I haven't tested it so the last line might need playing around with slightly but I've used something very similar so would expect it to work.

You can then use `foundContact[0]` to reference the contact found and use the further methods of `.getFullname()` `.getId()` etc. to retrieve their data as required.  If you need the contacts phone numbers or geographical address that's a whole other process of returning an array of objects using `.getPhones()` or `getAddresses()`, but I think that's beyond the scope of this question.